# Automated Testing - Support multiple tested program versions

Tags: testing, automation, backwards-compatibility

General Info:

1) Automation Java project.

2) Tested program has a new version every 6 mounts (give or take).

Needed - adding backward-compatibility to my automation code, meaning - a change on my Java code that won't support old version of my program, won't affect working with older versions.

I was wondering what's the best methodology to maintain a version list of my tested program and a java code for each version.
Since I don't want code re-writing, I guess that I want somthing like that:

code-A works for versions V1-V4, and Code-A-new works for version V5 and above.

code B works for version V1, code-B-new works for versions V2-V3, code-B-newer works for 
version V4 and above

and so on...

When trying to read about the subject on-line I found an article (http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/designing-for-backwards-compatibility.html?m=1) that suggested a factory for the matter.

I'll be glad for any guidness.

Comment: I guess the dev team is branching out those versions of the program in the SCM, no? If so, then you should branch out your test as well. Trying to keep a single version of your tests for multiple versions of the product might become more complicated than branching IMHO.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is what we're currently doing. I was wondering if there is a better solution, that will give us one developed project for all